# Cannot install spork with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spork

I am following micheal hartl's ruby on rails tutorial and am stuck where he installs spork for autotesting .

I do an install of spork and it shows succesfully installed and then I am trying to run the command (spork) in the terminal and this is the error I am getting . Any lead on it please ? Don't know , but spork's github repo seems to lack direction on installing it and the common problems people are facing on it.

P.S :: I already ran spork --bootstrap

```
Using RSpec
/Users/Arjo/rails_testprojects/proto1/spec/spec_helper.rb has not been bootstrapped.  Run       spork --bootstrap to do so.
Preloading Rails environment
no such file to load -- spork/forker.rb (LoadError)
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/activesupport-   3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/gems/spork-0.9.2/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/Arjo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@twitclone/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you add it to your Gemfile?  And run bundle install?

Comment: Since `spork --bootstrap` was run, I'm guessing that the spork gem has already been installed, but it's possible it's only in the `:development` group in the Gemfile and not in the `:test` group, or something like that.  It does appear that at runtime it's unable to locate all of the spork gem, so I think @digidigo is on to something.

Comment: @digidigo : that indeed was the problem . and after that I open another terminal tab and write in autotest and it's giving me that command not found.

Answer (score 0):

add gem 'spork' into Gemfile, bundle install and try again.